# Query multiple values from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

New to SQL and I am struggling with a query to have multiple values from a column counted and added together.  Here is the query

```
select count (*) as NEWCOL
from table1
where COL1 = 'val1' and COL2 = 'val1' and COL3='val1' or 'val2'
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to explain what you trying to achieve here!!

Comment: More details and sample values would help

Comment: How can there be answers already when nobody has any clue what OP is trying to do?

Comment: do you just want to count the occurrences of particular values in the goiven columns or do you actually wnat to convert these values into numbers and add them up ?

Comment: If you want both count and the values added together, I believe you mean concatenated since you're comparing the value to a varchar(4), I am writing a solution up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your where condition looks flawed:

```
select count (*) as NEWCOL
  from table1
  where COL1 = 'val1'
    and COL2 = 'val1'
    and (COL3 = 'val1' or COL3 = 'val2')
      ;
```

Comment: I think you're missing the 'Added together' part.

Comment: @WickedFan That's correct but that's also the part which the OP needs to elaborate on.

Comment: I overlooked using parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(y.*) as NewCol
  ,x.[allfields] as WhatyouWantitToBe
FROM 
  table1 y
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT 
     x.col1 + ' ' + x.col2 + ' ' + x.col3 AS [allFields]
   FROM
     table1 x
   WHERE
     x.col1 = y.col1
     AND
       x.col2 = y.col2
     AND
       x.col3 = y.col3) AS x
WHERE 
  y.COL1 = 'val1'
  AND y.COL2 = 'val1'
  AND (y.COL3 = 'val1' 
       OR 
       y.COL3 = 'val2')
```

And then again, that's what can be done with what you mentioned. A concatenation of varchar field as well as a count.